# Strange Entries in Tag RSS Feeds

Tags: discussion, rss

I'm using the RSS feeds for several tags so I can keep up to date on them. Occasionally, I get an entry that shows up and the question was asked several months ago.  If I look at the RSS feed the entry has an updated date but it doesn't appear that anything has changed on the page for the question:

```
<published>2010-05-24T12:30:25Z</published>
<updated>2011-02-01T19:18:34Z</updated>
```

This is the feed I'm looking at: https://serverfault.com/feeds/tag/sharepoint and this is the question that showed up this afternoon: [recyle application pool,Warm up scripts-Performance tuning in Sharepoint WCM site](https://serverfault.com/questions/144825/recyle-application-pool-warm-up-scripts-performance-tuning-in-sharepoint-wcm-site) .

Has anyone else had this problem and know why it's happening.  It's just a minor annoyance but it's strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon the `<updated>` tag gets updated when the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) randomly pokes old questions, like it did that question at the time it says it was updated.

Comment: correct, and a question must be answered by our definition.. have at least one answer **with at least one upvote** to avoid getting poked.

Comment: Thanks guys it's been driving me nuts.